# Reusablity in Ext JS 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, reusability

I have a lot of reusable code in my project (Some GUIs, grids, etc.).  Does Extjs 4 provide any functionality for handling reusable code?
Example:  Java has the functionality for libraries that can be imported into any project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ExtJs offers a high level of reusability if you know its core well.

These various concepts come to mind:

## The Class System

One of the most powerful features of ExtJs is that everything is organised into a class hierarchy, so essentially the design philosophy is similar to that in JAVA or C++.

For instance, consider that your grids never show headers. You would write:

```
Ext.define('HeadlessGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    hideHeaders: true,
});
```

So `HeadlessGrid` inherits from `Ext.grid.Panel` and just modifies its `hideHeaders` config. You can alter many other config of a component, but also its behaviour which is done by overriding its methods.

Sometimes, instead of subclassing Ext classes, you want the Ext classes themselves to change.

So something like this:

```
Ext.override( Ext.grid.Panel, {
    hideHeaders: true,
});
```

Means that all grid component will not show headers by default.

## Namespaces

The concept of 'library' can be achieved using namespaces. So to carry on with the previous example, you might have:

```
Ext.define('Ext.Juice.HeadlessGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    hideHeaders: true,
});
```

Now `HeadlessGrid` belongs to the `Ext.Juice` namespace.

You can set your class loader like so:

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.Juice', '../../libs/Juice');
```

And now any classes under that folder are reusable by any application you write.

## Plugins

Plugins allow you to extend (visible) component by means of composition instead of inheritance. So adding this plugin to any grid will hide the headers:

```
Ext.define("Ext.plugin.Decapitator", {
    extend   : "Ext.AbstractPlugin",
    alias    : "plugin.decapitator",

    init : function( aPanel ) { 
        aPanel.hideHeaders = true;
    },

});
```

## Mixins

Mixins allow you to mix classes together, very much like multiple inheritance.

The following code (from the docs) mixes the `CanSing` class with a `Musician` class.

```
Ext.define('CanSing', {
     sing: function() {
         alert("I'm on the highway to hell...")
     }
});

Ext.define('Musician', {
     mixins: ['CanSing']
})
```

Answer (score 4):

@Mchl,

Are you using MVC structure or general structure of extjs 4.x version.
If you are using MVC structure you can create a separate folder inside app folder (*there already exists folder named view, model, controller*), eg. app/component . And create class using as

Ext.define('MyApp.component.componentName', {.....});

Note you will have to include the Ext.require('MyApp.component.componentName') to preload the code.

Comment: Raj is the question owner and not Mchl ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can define a class with `Ext.define` and reuse it throughout your application with `Ext.create` (or with using xtypes).

If you need the same screens/classes in other projects you can just copy the file where you defined your class and use it.

**Example:**

```
//Defining Class
Ext.define('Stack.Overflow', {
    alias: 'widget.SO',

    someProperty: 'something',
    someMethod: function(s) {
        alert(s + this.someProperty);
    }
});

//Creating class with Ext.create:
var myClass = Ext.create('Stack.Overflow', {
    extraProperty: 1337
});

//Creating component inline:
var panel = Ext.widget('panel', { // Equivalent to Ext.create('widget.panel')
    title: 'Panel',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'SO',
        extraColor: '#BADA55'
    },{
        xtype: 'SO', //reusable class
        extraColor: '#FFFF00'
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's.... the same... Put the components you want to reuse in a library, then use `Ext.require()` to import it to your projects.

Comment: Hi Machl,
I am new in Ext JS. Can you give me one small example for the same.